# ClassNotFoundException on weblogic cluster node

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We have a web application(.war) deployed on a weblogic 10.3.4 cluster in 'staging' mode.
So,the .war is copied over to the staging directory of the nodes;and the application is responding to user requests fine.
However,we get a ClassNotFoundException when a  processor class tries to invoke an action class dynamically.
(Note: Processor and action have nothing to do with any of the frameworks.It is just a nomenclature.)

```
protected Action getAction(String sActionName) throws ActionException {

        Action action = null;
        Object o = null;

        try {
            String sClassName = getActionClassName(sActionName);
            Class actionClass = Class.forName(sClassName);
            o = actionClass.newInstance();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return action;
   }
```

We have verified that the class exists within the war and can be instantiated just fine through an independent application.
Why cant the node not find it then?
Do we need to point the application .war from the staging directory to weblogic classpath explicitly?
That would be quite odd.

Comment: Probably need to provide more detail. What is the exception/stack trace? How is your .war file packaged and where are the classes located that are causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check if your Classpath is correct using Weblogic CAT tool.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG495

> CAT is a Web-based class analysis tool which simplifies filtering classloader configuration and aids you in analyzing classloading issues, such as detecting conflicts, debugging application classpaths and class conflicts, and proposes solutions to help you resolve them